# Не получается передвинуть элемент

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

У меня есть в папке `layouts/application.html.erb` такой код (я использую devise):

```
<%= link_to 'Регистрация', new_user_registration_path, {id: 'sign-up-link'}%>
```

И в `stylesheets/custom.css.scss` такой код относительно этого `id`:

```
sign-up-link {
  margin-left: 135px;
}
```

У меня есть контейнер и весь этот css и ruby код относятся к нему. Проблема заключается в том, что я могу двигать ссылку "Регистрация" влево-вправо, но не могу вверх-вниз. Не могу понять, с чем это связано. Может как-то не так двигаю. Помогите пожалуйста, так же хотелось бы услышать какой-нибудь совет насчёт позиционирования элементов на веб-странице. Мне кажется, что так выставлять по пикселям не лучший вариант.

Я хочу "Регистрация" сделать на одном уровне с кнопкой "Войти".

Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CSS код должен выглядеть так, но при добавлении # текст становится бОльшего шрифта и полужирный.
#sign-up-link {
  margin-left: 135px;
}

Comment: Отформатировал код и картинку в вашем вопросе. Посмотрите, как это было сделано, пригодится для будущих вопросов: [edit]

Comment: @NickVolynkin скажите, как Вы сделали, чтобы после # текст не становился полужирным и другого шрифта?

Comment: а где я такое сделал?

Comment: # — элемент разметки Markdown, обозначающий заголовок. Но если его офрмить как блок кода, то он будет читаться буквально. Подробнее: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет. Дело в том, что ссылка - это, так называемый, **строчный(inline)** элемент. Их можно двигать только по горизонтали. А есть **блочные(block)** элементы, которые можно двигать и по горизонтали и по вертикали. Однако, с помощью CSS можно сделать строчный элемент блочным:

```css
#sign-up-link {
    display: inline-block; /* делаем элемент блочным */
    margin-left: 135px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

По поводу верстки: вариант позиционирования по пикселям вполне нормальный.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Можно двигать по пикселям, сделав элементы блочными, но также вы можете использовать свойство CSS `vertical-align: middle` для inline элементов - они сравняются автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать `padding-top` для контейнера, в который вложена ссылка. Если контейнер отсутствует, то создать его.